# Can I write a python code and plug it in a C# based website?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, web, recommendation-engine

I am recently working on writing a code for a recommender engine for a website using python, on jupyter Notebook.

Do I have to rewrite the code in C# to script it in the web page, or there is a way to plug the python code into C#. I have very limited knowledge in C#. Perhaps, I can reduce my coding time without rewriting the whole thing again.

Comment: Why did you even start writing it in python if you knew you will probably need it in C#? But that aside: what do you mean with "plug into website"? Are you talking about a web application in ASP/.Net?

Comment: Because they easiest way to build a recommender system is through python and its famous libraries (TensorFlow, Keras, Numpy....), however, if you suggest an implementation in C# it will be great.

Comment: I am not suggesting anything. I was just curious why you would spend a lot of effort for a code you know you cannot really use in the target environment. But I'll always agree with "the best tool for the job" - so now it's time to look if there is a better way than the one I linked above or if that even works for you.